# Вылетает приложение на некоторых устройства (Fragment!)

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction

У меня такая проблемка есть. На моем устройстве все хорошо, на некоторых других тоже.
Но у большинства приложение вылетает при замене фрагмента. Их logcat отследить не могу, они не разбираются в этом. Пробовал отключать все, кроме inflate в onCreateView и в onViewCreated все отключал, не помогло. Помогло только отключение показа фрагмента.

Мой код (MainActivity) :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadFragment(new HomeFragment());
}
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Код HomeFragment:

```
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rustate_launcher_home_fragment, container, false);
        processProgress = view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_process);
        processText = view.findViewById(R.id.process_text);
        serverName = view.findViewById(R.id.serverName);
        serverStatus = view.findViewById(R.id.server_status);
        serverPing = view.findViewById(R.id.server_ping);
        serverPlayersCount = view.findViewById(R.id.players_count);
        playBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_game);
        forumBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.button_forum);
        donateBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.button_donate);
        settingsBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.button_settings);
        news = view.findViewById(R.id.news_bg);
        newsText = view.findViewById(R.id.news_text);
        newsBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.news_btn);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Initialize();
        if(BGNativeFunctions.BGCoreNative__isInternetConnected(getActivity())) {
            loadingAPI();
            loadingServerData();
        } else {
            processText.setText("Нет подключения к интернету.");
        }
        if(Utils.getInstallType() == Utils.INSTALL_TYPE_REINSTALL) {
            File game = new File(GAME_PATH);
            if(game.exists()) { game.delete(); }
            startDownload(2);
            Utils.setInstallType(0);
        }
    }

Но опять же скажу, это все я отключал и мне это не помогло, тоесть дело не в этом.

MainActivity Layout:
```

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Fragment layout:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1f1f1f"
    android:gravity="center">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="689dp"
        android:layout_height="364dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="637dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_launcher_header"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.307"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo_russian_state" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
                android:text="RUSSIAN\nSTATE"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_forum"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_launcher_button"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montsserat_semibold"
                android:text="Форум"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.545" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_donate"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_launcher_button"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montsserat_semibold"
                android:text="Донат"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_forum"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.545" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_settings"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_launcher_button"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montsserat_semibold"
                android:text="Настройки"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_donate"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.545" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="204dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_launcher_header"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/news_bg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_news_test_bg" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
                android:text="ПРОВЕРКА"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/news_btn"
                android:layout_width="81dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_news_btn_bg"
                android:text="Подробнее"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
            android:layout_width="362dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_launcher_header"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.045"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/process_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
                android:text="Нет соединения с сервером..."
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/progressbar_process"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar_process"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/process_percent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.724" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/process_percent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
                android:text="100%"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/process_text"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.617" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout4"
            android:layout_width="232dp"
            android:layout_height="107dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_launcher_header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_start_game"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.094">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/serverName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
                android:text="RUSSIAN STATE"
                android:textColor="#ff2723"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/server_info_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
                android:text="Статус сервера:\nКоличество игроков:\nПинг:"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.183"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/serverName"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.44" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/server_info_text"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.633">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/players_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
                    android:text="1000/1000"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/server_status"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/server_ping"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
                    android:text="1000"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/players_count"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/server_status"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
                    android:text="Неизвестно"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
            android:text="Сервера"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.01"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_start_game"
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_play"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout3"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Если что, activity_main.xml обычный, а фрагмент - landscape. В AndroidManifest я указал, чтоб всегда был landscape.

[image: как выглядит лайот фрагмента]

Comment: забыл указать, что проблема не зависит от версии android. У кого то на 11 норм, у кого то не запускается, у кого то на 8-9 норм, у кого то опять же, не запускается. 
У меня 8.1 и все хорошо.

Comment: Андроид студио предоставляет все версии андроида, неужели не можете проверить?

Comment: И сделайте debug  сборку пользователям. Будет сохранена ошибка, с указанием строки и причины ошибки

Comment: Все, нашел причину и исправил. В logcat на проблемных устройствах выходила кое какая ошибка, загуглив я нашел решение - переместить ресурсы с большим разрешением из drawable в drawable-xxdpi